# How to use multiSelect in Material-Ui in react js?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

ui multi select in my project. I am displaying selected value using `renderValue` prop of `Select`.
Here is my code -

```
<Select
      labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
      id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
      multiple
      value={studentList!}
      renderValue={SelectedData(studentList!)}
>
      {studentList && studentList.map((studentListData: any) => (
         <MenuItem key={studentListData.stuId} value={studentListData.studentName!}>
            <Checkbox checked={studentListData.good} />
            <ListItemText primary={studentListData.studentName} />
         </MenuItem>
      ))}
</Select>
```

and below code for `SelectedData` function -

```
let blankArray = [];
    const Demo = (studentList:any): React.ReactNode => {
        studentList.map((studentName :string) => {
            blankArray.push(studentList.studentName);
        });     
        return blankArray.join(", ");
    }
```

This Demo function is not working in renderValue. Showing error - `Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type '((value: unknown) => ReactNode) | undefined'.  Type 'null' is not assignable to type '((value: unknown) => ReactNode) | undefined'.`
but if I do like `renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}` then it's working fine. I want to create separate const method like I did above, don't wanna render function inside `renderValue`. Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

> don't wanna render function inside `renderValue`

But that's exactly what `renderValue` expects/requires.  A function.  Specifically of type: `(value: unknown) => ReactNode`.

If your `SelectedData` function returns a `ReactNode` then you can just wrap it in a function to pass to that property:

```
renderValue={() => SelectedData(studentList!)}
```

---

Or, perhaps you simply forgot to return `Demo` from `SelectedData`?  It's not entirely clear if the code you're showing is the *entirety* of `SelectedData`.  In which case you can still do this:

```
renderValue={SelectedData(studentList!)}
```

But `SelectedData` needs to return the type that `renderValue` expects.  Something like:

```
let blankArray = [];
const Demo = (studentList:any): React.ReactNode => {
    studentList.map((studentName :string) => {
        blankArray.push(studentList.studentName);
    });     
    return blankArray.join(", ");
}
return Demo;
```

---

Any way you look at it, what you need to pass to `renderValue` needs to be of type `(value: unknown) => ReactNode`.

Comment: It's not entirely `SelectedData` I have some other things to render as well. If I will return `Demo` then I won't be able to return or render my JSX part.

Comment: @AnuragMishra: Then what *does* `SelectedData` return?  The error message implies that it returns `ReactNode | null`, so the first option of wrapping it in a function should work.  The overall solution is always the same... Whatever you pass to `renderValue` needs to be a function that returns a `ReactNode`.